# javascript remove only object from array by using filter failed

Tags: javascript, arrays, filter

```js
let c = [{tenantId:1, cost:30}];
let b = c.filter(x => x.tenantId == 1);
alert(b.length);
```

When i create the array c with only object in it as above code, i expect the b.length is 0, but it is 1. However, when add another object into the array c and then do the same filter operation, i got the expected answer, which the b.length equals 1.(2 objects filtered 1 and left 1). Does anyone knows why it happens?

Comment: Hey @Chris Welcome to SO. Did you go through the filter documentation? If not, I highly recommend you do that. A 'filter' function returns a new array with all of the items that pass a certain criteria mentioned inside the filter function. When you have only one item and you use the filter on it with same match, it means that you are extracting all of those items that match those criteria.

Comment: Tushar Shukla, i just realized that, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`.filter` **keeps** elements matching the test, rather than removing them.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter

If you can `console.log()` the whole array instead of simply the length, you will be able to see what it contains. Alternatively, you could `alert(JSON.stringify(b))`.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't read the document, just from the literal meaning of Filter, I thought Filter is to directly return the object that does not match the conditions. thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```js
let c = [{tenantId:1, cost:30}];
let b = c.filter(x => x.tenantId != 1);
console.log(b.length);
```

You need to add `x.tenantId != 1` this line of code.

Answer (score 0):

Just switch the `==` to `!==` and you're good.

**Why?:**

The `filter` method will keep all elements that return true when passed through your condition. In your original code, you are telling filter to "Please keep all objects in this array where `tenantId` is equal to `1`". If you want to remove these, you should tell it "Please keep all objects where `tenantId` doesn't equal `1`"

```js
const arr = [{ tenantId: 1, cost: 30 }];
const filtered = arr.filter(({ tenantId }) => tenantId !== 1);
console.log(filtered, `Length: ${filtered.length}`);
```